# Modify Pointer Value

Tags: c++, pointers

Really dumb question, but I am very confused.

So, my understanding is that if you have:

```
int i(3);
int& j(i);
int* k(&i);
```

In this case, if the value of `j` changes, then the value of `i` will also change, because `j` is basically an alias of `i`? On the other hand, if we make `k` point to something else, then the value of `i` and `j` will not change at all, right?

If the above is true, then if we have:

```
a = 1; b = 2;
p = &a; q = &b;
*p = *q;
```

Then why the value of `a` changes to 2? I thought `p` merely points to something else and that does not modify the value of `a`?

Answer (score 1):

Conjecture 1 is correct.

So long as `k` is pointing at `i` (and by the way `int* k(&j);` will also point `k` at `i` because `j` IS `i`) `*k=10;` will set `i` to `10`.  If you point `k` somewhere else then `*k=10;` will change whatever it now point at.

But in the second part, nothing ever changes `p` to point away from `a`, so writing to `*p` will change `a`. `q` is entirely separate from `p`, so pointing `q` at `b` simply means `q` points at `b` and `*p = *q;` is effectively `a=b` Change where either of those pointers points and you'll get a different result.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, `i` is a variable, with a number of properties - two of those are an address in memory and a name (`i`).   `j` is an alias for `i`, so is simply an alternative name for the same memory location as `i`.  Or, to put it another way, the underlying memory location has two names - one name is `i` and the other is `j`.

Any operations that affect the underlying memory simultaneously change the values of both `i` and `j`.  So assigning to `i` affects (via the memory location) the value of `j`, and vice versa.  For example, `i = 42` will work by changing the content of the underlying memory location and, since `j` is an alternative name for the same memory location, will cause the condition `j == 42` to be true, and vice versa.

`k` is a variable which contains the address of `i` (i.e. the address of the underlying memory location).  Assigning to `*k` affects the memory location, so changes `i` and therefore `j`.  For example, `*k = 21` will cause `i == 21 && j == 21` to be true.

One key difference between a pointer and a reference is that a pointer can be reassigned (so it contains the address of a different memory location) but a reference cannot.   So it is not possible to associate either `i` or `j` with a different memory location.   Whereas,  the assignment `k = &some_other_int` will cause `k` to contain the address of `some_other_int` - and `k` will no longer have any association with `i` or `j`.  Doing anything with `*k` will affect the memory location that has the name `some_other_int`, but not the values associated with `i` or `j`.

In your second example, the value of `p` is the address of `a` and the value of `q` is the address of `b`.    However, the expression  `*p = *q` works by extracting the value at the memory location pointed to by `q` (i.e. the value of `b`) and assigning it into the memory location pointed to by `p` (which has the name `a`).   So `*p = *q` has the same net effect as `*p = b` or `a = b` or even `a = *b`.    In this sense, `*p` and `*q` can be viewed as references to (or alternative names or aliases of) `a` and `b` respectively.